Commerce Promotions => The calculated price is only displayed to logged in users
In the latest version of Drupal Commerce I created an unrestricted promotion with a percentage offer. Everything works perfectly. The newly calculated price is displayed correctly everywhere. Unfortunately, this only applies to the logged in user, regardless of his role.The anonymous user is shown the full price, including in his shopping cart. If the anonymous user logs in during the ordering process, the price is suddenly reduced by the specified percentage. If he logs out, he will see the non-reduced price again.
What could be the reason for this behavior?

OK, I think I found the solution. My promotion had only one restriction. Namely in the number of pieces per customer.This was enough to prevent anonymous users from seeing the reduced price.I think this is a bug, right?
